# Mutate column values based on previous row in another column

Tags: r

For the sake of reproducibility and transparancy, I'm trying to do something rather difficult for me in R (which I could easily do in Excel otherwise but not very reproducibly). Here's some data:

```
structure(list(Subject = c(500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 
502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 
502), Block = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Colour = c("GREEN", "RED", "RED", "GREEN", "RED", 
"GREEN", "RED", "RED", "GREEN", "GREEN", "RED", "GREEN", "GREEN", 
"RED", "RED", "RED", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "RED", "GREEN", 
"GREEN", "RED", "RED", "GREEN", "RED", "GREEN", "RED", "RED", 
"GREEN", "GREEN", "RED", "GREEN", "GREEN", "RED", "GREEN", "RED", 
"RED", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "RED", "GREEN", "RED", "RED", 
"RED", "RED"), Cong = c(21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 
22L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L
), CorrAns = c("GREEN", "RED", "circle", "triangle", "triangle", 
"GREEN", "triangle", "RED", "GREEN", "GREEN", "triangle", "GREEN", 
"GREEN", "RED", "triangle", "circle", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", 
"circle", "GREEN", "GREEN", "RED", "circle", "triangle", "triangle", 
"GREEN", "triangle", "RED", "GREEN", "GREEN", "triangle", "GREEN", 
"circle", "triangle", "GREEN", "RED", "triangle", "triangle", 
"GREEN", "GREEN", "RED", "GREEN", "triangle", "RED", "circle", 
"triangle"), CorrResp = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), Jitter1 = c(646L, 1294L, 639L, 1194L, 
758L, 1205L, 942L, 542L, 1256L, 1250L, 1031L, 1486L, 1426L, 1123L, 
1306L, 1426L, 1037L, 1208L, 1201L, 842L, 646L, 646L, 1294L, 639L, 
1194L, 758L, 1205L, 942L, 542L, 1256L, 1250L, 1031L, 1486L, 1342L, 
822L, 741L, 589L, 1025L, 914L, 1382L, 1384L, 875L, 615L, 922L, 
1296L, 923L, 595L), Jitter2 = c(1146L, 1794L, 1139L, 1694L, 1258L, 
1705L, 1442L, 1042L, 1756L, 1750L, 1531L, 1986L, 1926L, 1623L, 
1806L, 1926L, 1537L, 1708L, 1701L, 1342L, 1146L, 1146L, 1794L, 
1139L, 1694L, 1258L, 1705L, 1442L, 1042L, 1756L, 1750L, 1531L, 
1986L, 1842L, 1322L, 1241L, 1089L, 1525L, 1414L, 1882L, 1884L, 
1375L, 1115L, 1422L, 1796L, 1423L, 1095L), Procedure.Trial. = c("TrialProc2", 
"TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", 
"TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", 
"TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", 
"TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc5", 
"TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", 
"TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", 
"TrialProc2", "TrialProc2", "TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", 
"TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", 
"TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", "TrialProc5", 
"TrialProc5"), Shape = c("circle", "triangle", "circle", "triangle", 
"triangle", "triangle", "triangle", "circle", "triangle", "circle", 
"triangle", "triangle", "circle", "circle", "triangle", "circle", 
"circle", "triangle", "circle", "circle", "triangle", "circle", 
"triangle", "circle", "triangle", "triangle", "triangle", "triangle", 
"circle", "triangle", "circle", "triangle", "triangle", "circle", 
"triangle", "triangle", "circle", "triangle", "triangle", "triangle", 
"circle", "circle", "circle", "triangle", "circle", "circle", 
"triangle"), Shift = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 
219L, 220L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 
426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I'm trying to do is to mutate the rows in column `Shift` that have values `2` to a value `7` or `8` based on the preceding row, within that participant only. The rule is:

- if participants have to respond to `RED` or `GREEN` (colours) both in the preceding and the current trial, the current trial counts as a stay trial and should be mutated from a `2` to a `7`.
- if participants have to respond to `triangle` or `circle` (shapes) both in the preceding and the current trial, the current trial counts as a stay trial and should be mutated from a `2` to a `7`.
- if participants have to respond to `triangle` or `circle` (shapes) in the preceding BUT to `RED` or `GREEN` (colours) in the current (or the other way around), the current trial counts as a shift trial and should be mutated from a `2` to an `8` in `Shift` column.

Also, if the current trial is their first data row (i.e. their first trial), it should be mutated to a `7`. I imagine my code something like the below but I can't figure out how to make it work or specifically - refer to the previous row:

```
exampledata %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  mutate(Shift = case_when((CorrAns %in% "RED" | CorrAns %in% "GREEN") 
                           && (CorrAns %in% "RED" | CorrAns %in% "GREEN") ~ 7), #if previous trial is the same
         Shift = case_when((CorrAns %in% "triangle" | CorrAns %in% "circle") 
                           && (CorrAns %in% "RED" | CorrAns %in% "GREEN") ~ 8), #if previous trial is different
         Shift = case_when((CorrAns %in% "RED" | CorrAns %in% "GREEN") 
                           && (CorrAns %in% "triangle" | CorrAns %in% "circle") ~ 8), #if previous trial is different
         Shift = case_when((CorrAns %in% "triangle" | CorrAns %in% "circle") 
                           && (CorrAns %in% "triangle" | CorrAns %in% "circle") ~ 7), #if previous trial is the same
         Shift = case_when() ~ 7) #if previous trial is the first trial
```

If anyone has suggestions, I'll be very thankful!

Finally, here are is my version info (OS is Windows): "R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)"

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the requirements here. Could you provide the expected output.

For previous record have a look at `lag` function. But I suspect you might be able to achieve this by grouping on all the variables that define a trial and then doing a `row_number()  + 6`  mutation.

Comment: Hi there! I'm trying to mutate specific values (```2```) in the trials depending on the previous trial for that ```Subject``` number. However, all other non-2 values are either 7 or 8 anyways, so they should remain unchanged. The 2's are actually some codes for warm-up trials that I've decided to use eventually and consequently need to recode to either a 7, or an 8, depending on the previous trial. Not sure if that makes more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood, but I don't get why do you need the previous row? If you want only the first row to be 7 and the other 8 then the code snippet below will do the work.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  mutate(shift_new = case_when( (CorrAns %in% c('GREEN', 'RED')) &
                                  (lag(CorrAns) %in% c('GREEN', 'RED')) &
                                  Shift == 2 ~ 7,
                                (CorrAns %in% c('triangle', 'circle')) &
                                  (lag(CorrAns) %in% c('triangle', 'circle')) &
                                  Shift == 2 ~ 7, 
                                (CorrAns %in% c('triangle', 'circle')) &
                                  (lag(CorrAns) %in% c('GREEN', 'RED')) &
                                  Shift == 2 ~ 8,
                                (CorrAns %in% c('GREEN', 'RED')) &
                                  (lag(CorrAns) %in% c('triangle', 'circle')) &
                                  Shift == 2 ~ 8)) %>% 
  mutate(shift_new = coalesce(shift_new, Shift))
```

coalesce is to remove NAs and place the values of Shift instead.

Comment: I need the previous row because the previous trial defines what the current trial is. It's just based on the way my experiment works. I'd like to mutate all the rows with a value ```2``` according to their preceding row, as opposed to setting them all to the same value.

Comment: How exactly does it define it? Can you give a small example of how to output should look ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can paste big chunks of data as a comment but the previous trial defines whether the current trial is a shift or stay trial. By that I mean, if participants need to respond to ```GREEN``` or ```RED``` (colours) in the previous trial, and then respond on colours on the current trial, then it's ```7``` (a repeat trial). On the other hand, if in the previous they have to respond to ```triangle``` or ```circle``` (shapes), while in the current to colours (or the other way round), then it's a shift trial that should be coded as an ```8``` in ```Shift``` column.

Comment: Note also that this is the way all trials are currently coded in ```Shift``` column (according to the above rules), except the warmup trial that at this moment have the value of ```2```. I'd like to include these warmup trials in my analysis, hence I need to recode them as shift (```8```) or stay (```7```) trials in ```Shift``` column.

Comment: Is what I've added is what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thank you! That is exactly what I was trying to do. Didn't know about ```lag()``` and ```lead()```, so this is also a useful future reference!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by creating an indicator column that defines shapes vs colors, and then subtract the difference between that indicator and its lag from 8, as below:

```
exampledata %>%
  mutate(typ = if_else(CorrAns %in% c("GREEN","RED"),0,1)) %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  mutate(Shift = coalesce(8-(typ==lag(typ)),7))
```